Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments [...] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension
Im having error building appbundle for a project in flutter. Whenever building, Im having this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/JP/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-2.27.0/android/build.gradle' line: 55

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_core'.
> Could not find method kotlinOptions() for arguments [build_cn7tqacxu2xc1m49ym5jhj2ab$_run_closure1$_closure7@35e21027] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             19.7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I tried several times configuring the ff. files and I'm stuck in an endless loop of errors:

android/build.gradle:

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


android/app/build.gradle:

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.hmc.mobileapps.mosaic.prestige"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hmc.mobileapps.mosaic.prestige"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // FCM Fallback Delivery
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'
}


gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10-all.zip


settings.gradle:

pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

include ":app"

From flutter doctor --verbose:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 13.7.1 22H221 darwin-x64, locale en-PH)
    • Flutter version 3.24.5 on channel stable at /Users/JP/_SDK/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision dec2ee5c1f (5 weeks ago), 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
    • Engine revision a18df97ca5
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/JP/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/JP/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Users/JP/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915915-b509.11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15C500b
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at /Users/JP/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-79915915-b509.11)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/JP/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2024.2.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/JP/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.app
    • Flutter plugin version 83.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 242.24931

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/JP/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 15 Pro Max (mobile) • A74F75E8-D685-4AE8-A990-8495C15EF811 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)            • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.7.1 22H221 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.140

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

I don't know if I'm missing anything else. I also tried asking AI for and haven't got the correct fix. Please help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Adding  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' under plugins  on build.gradle(Project) did resolve it for me

You're obviously missing the org.jetbrains.kotlin.android alias kotlin-android plugin.
It has to be loaded in the top-level build.gradle, then it can be applied on module-level.
kotlinOptions() is deprecated since 2.0.0-Beta5 and had been replaced with kotlin().

Hi thanks a lot for the reply. Sorry I did not quite get it. Can you give the code for this and where to put it?

Nope. There's no code in the question either and I've already explained where to put it.

I added code, hope this help.
